# How to get Google calendar's "Location" setting via Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

When creating a Google calendar or modifying its settings via the UI, there is a "**Location**" field. I'd like to get the value of that field via Google Apps Script (GAS).

Unfortunately, it appears to either be undocumented or not exposed through [the GAS Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar). I've searched the net as well as SO, but I want to make sure I'm not overlooking something.

**Please Note**: I'm not referring to an event location, but rather the "Location" field of the calendar itself, which is entered via "Calendar settings" in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar):

> The advanced Calendar service allows you to use the public [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) in Apps Script. Much like Apps Script's [built-in Calendar service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar), this API allows scripts to access and modify the user's Google Calendar, including additional calendars that the user is subscribed to. In most cases, the built-in service is easier to use, but this advanced service provides a few extra features, including setting the background color for individual events.

Then read the [Calendars](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars) reference.

Resource representations:

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#calendar",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "summary": string,
  "description": string,
  "location": string,
  "timeZone": string
}
```

Note:

> **location** - Geographic location of the calendar as free-form text. Optional.

This mean that you can either get a location or not (if not set).

There are also Try this API for [Calendars: insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert) and [Calendars: get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) to see how Calendar - location works.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With the [Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/) in Google Apps Script there are two methods for setting location. With the [`createEvent()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object)) method you can include location and other metadata in the `options` parameter:

```
// Creates an event for the moon landing and logs the ID.
var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent('Apollo 11 Landing',
     new Date('July 20, 1969 20:00:00 UTC'),
     new Date('July 20, 1969 21:00:00 UTC'),
     {location: 'The Moon'});
Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
```

Alternatively there is a [`setLocation()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setLocation(String)) method for a `CalendarEvent` e.g.

```
// Creates an event for the moon landing and logs the ID.
var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent('Apollo 11 Landing',
     new Date('July 20, 1969 20:00:00 UTC'),
     new Date('July 20, 1969 21:00:00 UTC'));
event.setLocation('The Moon');
Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, it seems you didn't thoroughly read my question. I'm inquiring about how to get the value in the "Location" field of a **Calendar** object – not an event. There are methods for getting the calendar description, timezone, etc. - but not location (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: Calendars don't have locations so what you are asking is not possible :)

Comment: Indeed they do, and indeed it is possible as @Mr.Rebot described. The advanced calendar service must be explicitly enabled for the script as well as in the developer console. Then you can do `var gcalInfo = Calendar.Calendars.get( gcalId ); var loc = gcalInfo.location || "unspecified location";`